Show that if a subset of $C([0,1])$ is open relative to one norm it is also open relative to another or vice versa
I am struggling coming up with a solution to the following question. Consider the two norms $||f||_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)| \mathrm{d}x$ and $||f||_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f(x)|$ on $C([0,1])$ (the vector space of all continuous functions $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$). If $A \subset C([0,1 ])$ is open relative to $||\cdot||_1$ is it also open relative to $||\cdot||_\infty$ or the other way around?
I seem to have problems solving these kinds of questions so I would highly appreciate any kind of help on this one. Many thanks in advance!

In metric spaces, a subset $U$ is open if and only if for all $x \in U$, there is an open ball $B_x$ around $x$ such that $B_x \subseteq U$. Try using this to show that open balls in one norm are open sets in the other.

The identity $id:(C([0,1]), |\cdot|_\infty) \to (C([0,1]), |\cdot|_1)$ is continuous. Hence if $A \subseteq C([0,1])$ is open in  $(C([0,1]), |\cdot|1)$, then $A=id^{-1}(A)$ is open in $(C([0,1]), |\cdot|\infty)$.

@Gerd The original question was to determine whether $\mathrm{Id}: (\mathcal{C}([0,1]), ||\cdot||_\infty) \to (\mathcal{C}([0, 1]), ||\cdot||_1)$ or $\mathrm{Id}: (\mathcal{C}([0,1]), ||\cdot||1) \to (\mathcal{C}([0, 1]), ||\cdot||\infty)$ is continous. I was trying to show that with the approach that I described above.

For starters, note that if a set is open in one topology if and only if it is open in the other, then the topologies are equivalent. However, these two topologies are not equivalent (since there are sequences of functions that converge in the $L^1$ norm and not in the sup norm).
It is true however that if a set is open in the $L^1$ norm, it is open in the sup norm, and this is a direct consequence of the fact that for every $f$ in our space, $\|f\|_1\leq\|f\|_{\infty}$. To see that, if $U$ is open in the $L^1$ norm, then given $f\in U$ there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that: $$\tilde{B}_{\varepsilon}(f)\subset B_{\varepsilon}(f)\subset U$$
Where $B$ is wrt the $L^1$ norm and $\tilde{B}$ is wrt to the sup norm.
Also another way of seeing it is since these are normed spaces, topologies are determined by the convergent sequences, and every sup convergent sequence is also $L^1$ convergent sequence.

I see how every sequence that is convergent wrt $||\cdot||_\infty$ must also converge wrt $||\cdot||_1$ since $||f||1 \leq ||f||\infty$. But I don't rly understand how that helps. What do you mean by "topologies are determined by the convergent sequences"? We didn't rly cover topologies only metric spaces and as far as I know only closed sets are determined by their limit points meaning that every convergent sequence with terms inside the set must also have its limit inside this set.

"It is true however that if a set is open in the sup norm, it is open in the $L^1$ norm," That is incorrect. If for example I take the open unit ball around the zero function in the sup norm, I can easily construct a continuous function of arbitrarily small $L^1$ norm that is not in it, by using a hat function with height $n$ but base length $1/n^2$.

@Ingix Fixed it, it is the other way around.
